# PHP string cut and save

Tags: php, string

i'm new in php and i will cut and save words (string).

example:

```
$string = "Pending order Verkaufen AUD/USD Preis 0.724 Take Profit bei 0.7202 Stop Loss bei 0.7292 ab dem 13:06 15-12-2015 GMT bis zum 17:06 15-12-2015 GMT";
```

cut in string:

```
$string1 = "verkaufen";
$string2 = "AUD/USD";
$string3 = "0.724";
$string4 = "0.7202";
$string5 = "0.7292";
$string6 = "15-12-2015";
$string7 = "13:06";
$string8 = "15-12-2015";
$string9 = "17:06";
```

we can i do this? Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want the `explode` function, which will separate your string by spaces:

```
$strings = explode(' ', $string);
```

This returns an array of the pieces of your `$string` between the spaces.

Comment: ah ok thank you.
but i need not all pieces. only the 9 pieces and now "difficult" the 9 elements varies repeatedly. Can i search the words before and than cut?

Comment: You can use `strpos` to find a specific word's location and `substr` to get just the substring after that word.

Comment: can i give back after strpos a word? or only with substr a fix 
length?